# Having a statement and reading the dates from another table

Tags: mysql, unions

I'm having some trouble with my following query:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date, "%Y-%m-%d") date, id, c, FromWhere FROM (
SELECT distinct cl.creationtime date, c.id, 1 c, "Created" as FromWhere -- Current amount of contacts in list
FROM `contactsLists` cl, `contacts` c
WHERE cl.contact=c.id AND c.optin="yes" AND c.restriction=0 AND cl.list = 13
AND cl.creationtime > DATE_SUB(now(), interval 13 MONTH)
UNION
SELECT IFNULL(cl.edittime, NOW()) date, c.id, -1 c, "Deleted from list" as FromWhere -- Deleted from list
FROM `contactsLists` cl, `contacts` c
WHERE cl.contact=c.id AND c.optin="yes" AND c.restriction=0 AND cl.deleted=1 AND cl.list = 13
AND IFNULL(cl.edittime, NOW()) > DATE_SUB(now(), interval 13 MONTH) 
UNION
SELECT o.optintime date, c.id, 1 c, "Optin added" as FromWhere -- Optins
FROM `contactsLists` cl, `contacts` c, `optin` o
WHERE cl.contact=c.id AND c.email = o.email AND o.reply="yes" AND c.restriction=0 AND cl.list = 13
AND o.optintime > DATE_SUB(now(), interval 13 MONTH)
UNION
SELECT o.optintime date, c.id, -1 c, "Optout added" as FromWhere -- Optouts
FROM `contactsLists` cl, `contacts` c, `optin` o
WHERE cl.contact=c.id AND c.email = o.email AND o.reply="no" AND c.restriction=0 AND cl.list = 13
AND o.optintime > DATE_SUB(now(), interval 13 MONTH)
ORDER BY date) u;
```

The problem is that the last 2 unions "Optins and Optouts" are reading the optin status o.reply="no"/"yes". But it reads the statement of the situation as now(). It should be read the optin reply while also checking the date at the same time from the o.optintime table. Is it possible todo so?

Everything else works in the query except for that. The idea of the graph is to show the growth or loss of a client database list.

Comment: I'm seeing the filter for o.reply and o.optintime. What's the problem? Are you saying this filter is incorrect? `o.optintime > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 13 MONTH) ` You want NOW() to be the date from optin table? What does optintime table look like?

Comment: No this filter is working perfectly, but the part where i declare wether optin="yes" or "no" it takes the current situation from my optin table. The thing is that i really need it to read the whole table or check the history instead of reading the current situation of the tables.

IT should be something like:
AND (o.reply="yes" AND "something else with o.optintime") 
Hope you understood :s, i'm not very good at explaining things

Comment: Hard to give you the right answer since I have very little information lol Here is my guess on what you're trying to do. I think you want to have another version of optin table (without filtering by 'reply'; instead you want full table). If so, you can add another 'optin o2' and join with that table. It's okay to join the same table twice if you want 2 different versions - one with filter and another without filter.

Comment: Hey Tin. Thanks for replying. i was working with the query and the problem was that it only read the result as one in one day. AKA on the 29th of February 2016 i had only one Optin status as Yes or No.
In different date, it reads multiple rows:
date id c FromWhere
2016-02-29 17:13:07 447872 1 Created
2016-02-29 17:22:01 447877 -1 Deleted from list
2016-03-01 13:16:55 447878 1 Optin added
2016-02-29 17:14:09 447871 -1 Optout added
2016-02-29 17:16:55 447878 -1 Optout added

I was worried about the client "447878"

But the query was working itself :)
Thanks again